# Most Efficiate Way to Change Position of Object in Array using Groovy

Tags: groovy

Assuming I have something like the following:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

And I have to change it to:

```
['a', 'b', 'f', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g']
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

UPDATE: I actually need the elements shifted, not swapped.  Note the change to my example above.

Comment: N.B. That's a list, not an array ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if by "efficient" you mean "in a clear/readable way", or if you're referring to performance. If it's the former and you want to do the replacement in-place, you can use the handy `[]` operator of lists:

```
def arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

arr[2, 5] = arr[5, 2]

assert arr == ['a', 'b', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'g']
```

**Update**: The question is not about swapping two elements, it's about moving an element to another position. To do that in-place, you can use some of the Java [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) methods that let you add and remove elements from a given position. I think this is quite readable:

```
def arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

arr.add(2, arr.remove(5))

assert arr == ['a', 'b', 'f', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g']
```

Comment: +1: Don't worry about optimization until your program runs slow. Then profile your program and finds out what function takes the most % of the time, and fix that. A single array re-arrangement will do nothing.

Comment: While this solves my question, I think I asked the question slightly incorrectly.  My problem isn't as simple as swapping.  It actually needs to shift the other elements. I'll update my question.

Comment: @Gregg updated answer :). I though i was just tripping or something when i saw your question again, for my answer had nothing to do with it (it's quite late here =P). I had to check the question's edits to verify i hadn't go nuts hehe.